# Is it possible to suppress hydration warnings for all nested children of a component in NextJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

> **Note:** I am using NextJS 14 but believe this is also a problem in NextJS 13

I have build a `ThemeToggle` component that uses `next-themes`. If I build out my own implementation of `next-themes` using React Context or any other state management solution I'll run into this same problem.

Here's my component:

```
"use client";

import { useTheme } from "next-themes";
import { FaSun, FaMoon } from "react-icons/fa";

export default function ThemeToggle() {
  const { theme, setTheme } = useTheme();

  return (
    <button onClick={() => setTheme(theme === "dark" ? "light" : "dark")}>
      {theme === "dark" ? <FaSun /> : <FaMoon />}
    </button>
  );
}
```

This is a client component because the `useTheme` hook is stateful and the server doesn't have the context of the `theme` state until it is rendered on the client.

This component works really well except for this annoying hydration warning that I get:

> app-index.js:31 Warning: Prop `d` did not match. Server: ...

This is clearly referring to the `d` prop of the underlying `svg` in my `react-icons` icons `FaSun` and `FaMoon`.

It makes sense that there is a mismatch here between client and server and I understand why this is occurring because according to the server, `theme` is `undefined` initially until the client renders which then defines what the theme is using `localStorage`.

I found that the recommended way to avoid this hydration error is to first check if the component is mounted before rendering my `FaSun` or `FaMoon` component. I accomplished this by rendering a fallback icon in place like this:

```
"use client";

import { useTheme } from "next-themes";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { FaSun, FaMoon } from "react-icons/fa";
import { TbFidgetSpinner } from "react-icons/tb";

export default function ThemeToggle() {
  const { theme, setTheme } = useTheme();
  const [isMounted, setIsMounted] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsMounted(true);
  }, []);

  return (
    <button onClick={() => setTheme(theme === "dark" ? "light" : "dark")}>
      {!isMounted ? (
        <TbFidgetSpinner className="animate-spin" />
      ) : theme === "dark" ? (
        <FaSun />
      ) : (
        <FaMoon />
      )}
    </button>
  );
}
```

### The Problem with this Approach

While this works and I no longer get the error, my user experience has deteriorated. Now whenever I change pages in my NextJS application is flashes to that fallback component.

The user experience was much better when I just had that server-client hydration mismatch, and the hydration mismatch isn't really a big deal considering the context is just that the server potentially won't render an icon correctly.

**Is there a way to suppress this hydration warning?**

### Things I've tried

- Use `next/dynamic` with the `ssr: false` flag

I've tried using `next/dynamic` to render my `ThemeToggle` component on its parent like this:

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'
const ThemeToggle = dynamic(() => import("./ThemeToggle"), { ssr: false })
```

This doesn't solve my UX problem with the loading, it actually makes it worse because that just hides the component on page change. If I use a `Suspense` in there it works the same as my `isMounted` implementation which is just as bad if not just a worse developer experience.

- use the `suppressHydrationWarning` prop

I tried to use the `suppressHydrationWarning` prop on the `button` and also the `FaSun` and `FaMoon` components like this:

```
<button
  onClick={() => setTheme(theme === "dark" ? "light" : "dark")}
  suppressHydrationWarning
>
  {theme === "dark" ?
    <FaSun suppressHydrationWarning /> :
    <FaMoon suppressHydrationWarning />
  }
</button>
```

Unfortunately the `suppressHydrationWarning` prop only applies directly the the element we're suppressing, not the underlying children. And given I can't update my `FaSun` and `FaMoon` components directly - since they come from a 3rd party library - this doesn't work.

### Current Work Around

I haven't tried this yet, but as of right now I believe the only way for me to get around this is to build my own sun and moon icons and apply the `suppressHydrationWarning` prop to the underlying affected elements directly. This isn't ideal but it will get the job done.

### Conclusion

Is there something I am missing with the go to solution around these kinds of warnings?

I don't want to turn of all hydration warnings because they are valuable, but I also don't want the ones that I expect to be lingering there. I also don't want to compromise the user experience.

Is there something that might exist like a `SuppressHydrationWarningBoundary` that will cover all underlying hydration warnings in a component that would work something like this?

```
<button onClick={() => setTheme(theme === "dark" ? "light" : "dark")}>
  <SuppressHydrationWarningBoundary>
    {theme === "dark" ? <FaSun /> : <FaMoon />}
  </SuppressHydrationWarningBoundary>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UX issue here was caused by something beyond the scope of this question.

I was using `a` tags instead of NextJS's `Link` component and that was causing the terrible flashes when changing pages.